# Tkinter program works fine in IDE (Visual Studio) but when using pyinstaller to compile to .exe threading does not work same like it does in IDE

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, python-multithreading

When I run my python project in my IDE the GUI and everything is responsive and works great. But when I run as .exe my threading components don't work like they do in IDE. The program's goal is to grab a live feed via RTSP and using opencv to display the images. This is done in its own thread here.

```
import time
import threading
import cv2
import PIL.Image


"""TODO: add docstring"""


class VideoCapture:

    def __init__(self, xmlDict=None, width=None, height=None, fps=None):
        """TODO: add docstring"""

        self.xmlDict = xmlDict
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = int(self.xmlDict['FPS'])

        self.running = False

        # Open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(self.xmlDict['IpAddress'])
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("[MyVideoCapture] Unable to open video source", xmlDict['IpAddress'])

        # Get video source width and height
        if not self.width:
            self.width = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))    # convert float to int
        if not self.height:
            self.height = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # convert float to int
        if not self.fps:
            self.fps = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))              # convert float to int

        # default value at start
        self.ret = False
        self.frame = None

        self.convert_color = cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB
        #self.convert_color = cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
        self.convert_pillow = True



        # start thread
        self.running = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        self.thread.start()

    def process(self):
        """TODO: add docstring"""

        while self.running:
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()

            if ret:
                # process image
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height))

                # it has to record before converting colors
              

                if self.convert_pillow:
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    frame = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
            else:
                print('[MyVideoCapture] stream end:', self.video_source)
                # TODO: reopen stream
                self.running = False
                if self.recording:
                    self.stop_recording()
                break

            # assign new frame
            self.ret = ret
            self.frame = frame

            # sleep for next frame
            #if self.fps != "FULL":
            #    time.sleep(1/int(self.fps))
```

I have a button setup called start that infers an image every 2 seconds and prints out the label and confidence. When I do this in .exe the live feed and GUI freeze while inference is being made but when I use program in IDE it does not freeze. Here is the code that does this.

```
#Button to start inference
self.btn_snapshot = tk.Button(self.btnFrame,width = 10,height = 2, text="Start", command=lambda:threading.Thread(target = self.snapshot).start())
self.btn_snapshot.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
#snapshot function

def snapshot(self):
        self.recording = True
        while self.recording:
            filename = self.vid.snapshot()  
            result = self.predictImage(filename)
            output = self.calculatePassFail(result)
            if self.manager:
                self.manager.onClick(output)
            else:
                print('something')

            time.sleep(2)
```

The other two methods that the snapshot function calls are predictImage and calculatePassFail.

```
    def predictImage(self,imageName):

        onnxModel = ImageModel.load(self.xmlDict['ModelPath'])
        result = onnxModel.predict_from_file(imageName)
        return result
        
                
    def calculatePassFail(self,result):
        calcResult = result.labels[0]
        self.labelName = calcResult[0]
        self.imgScore = calcResult[1]*100

        return f"{self.labelName} with score{self.imgScore}"
```

Comment: This is far too much code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve].

Comment: And it's not really enough to say *my threading components don't work like they do in IDE*. Please explain what is different or unsatisfactory or unexpected.

Comment: @BryanOakley I reduced the code down to the important pieces, I kept in the class VideoCapture just for context and only included the method where threading starts for it as well. I appreciate your feedback

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you for the response. I added a little bit more explanation. To summarize, the issue with threading occurs when I make an inference on an image. The live feed that is displayed on tkinter freezes along with the GUI itself until the image has a result.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a fix around this, not sure if its a proper fix but it works. So for some reason when I use pyinstaller to create .exe and there is a console window I have the issue but when I use the flag --noconsole when using pyinstaller to create w/out console the issue goes away and my inference on images acts in its own thread like it does in my IDE. Not sure why it does but it works I guess.